cy.get('#mat-radio-6').should('be.checked') I have used this syntax but it is giving me error
cy.get('#mat-radio-6').should('be.checked')

on running the above syntax following is the returned error:

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<mat-radio-button#mat-radio-6.mat-mdc-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-mdc-radio-checked>' to be 'checked'

HTML -
<mat-radio-button#mat-radio-6.mat-mdc-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-mdc-radio-checked>


Please share the HTML for the webpage. FWIW, the answer is in the error -> the element you've selected is not checked.

Add the child <input> to the selector - cy.get('#mat-radio-6 input').should('be.checked')

Or maybe the checked assertion is incorrect - try cy.get('#mat-radio-6').should('have.class', 'mat-radio-checked') - Changing material radio buttons options.
